# Size with an em value with a dot before

Tags: css

Will you please tell me if there is any difference between say writting

```
padding:.6em
```

and

```
 padding:0.6em;
```

and if it is the same value why don't we simply write

```
 padding:0.6em;
```

?

Thanks

Comment: It's the same :) Just as in maths .01 is the same as 0.01, the 0 isn't needed

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference. Without a leading 0 it's one byte less for those who are worried about it. Also, with a leading 0 might be slightly easier to read for some.

Comment: +1 , similar question could be too , why do i need to indent my code :) ... because we are human.

Answer (score 0):

They're exactly the same.

There is no visual difference in outcome by using `.6` or `0.6`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dcLVc/)

I think it's just down to personal preference.

Comment: You could also argue that the only difference is visual